# nginx location regex not working, how to enable regex?

Tags: nginx

In the nginx config I just want to use a regex for the location but I can't get any regex to work.

With a plain string in the location path it works and I can access the file from the browser. Here from my config:

```
location /profile/491ecdcd4.png {
    root /srv/www/XXX/code/app/public;
}
```

But I want to specify the folder for all png files, so I want to do it via regex. But as soon as I switch to regex with the `~*` I can't get it to work anymore. None of the following does work:

```
location ~* ^/profile/.*\.png$ {            # The regex like I would want it
location ~* /profile/491ecdcd4\.png$ {      # File name and line end
location ~* \/profile\/491ecdcd4\.png$ {    # Slashes escaped
location ~* "\/profile\/491ecdcd4\.png$" {  # Quotes around the regex
location ~* profile {                       # Just plain the path
```

If I specify the location like that, I get a 404 error when I try to access the png in the browser. `~` instead of `~*` also doesn't work.

The whole config is like that (shortened):

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name XXX;

    ssl                 on;
    ssl_certificate     /srv/www/XXX/certs/cacert.chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /srv/www/XXX/certs/privkey.pem;

    # Special treatment and the problematic section
    location ~* /profile/491ecdcd4.png {
        root /srv/www/XXX/code/app/public;
    }

    # For the rest
    location / {
        root /srv/www/XXX/code/app/build;
    }
}
```

```

Any ideas?

nginx version: nginx/1.6.2

edit: I edited the answer for clarity.

Comment: You have a related problem which may be preventing you from fixing this problem. See [root inside location block](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block). While this technically works, it's a smell, and it doesn't always do what you expect with a regex location.

Answer (score 3):

You should read "[understanding Nginx location block selection](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms)", particularly this part

> ```
> location optional_modifier location_match {
>    . . .
> }
> ```
>
> The location_match in the above defines what Nginx should check the
>   request URI against. The existence or nonexistence of the modifier in
>   the above example affects the way that the Nginx attempts to match the
>   location block. The modifiers below will cause the associated location
>   block to be interpreted as follows:
>
> - (none): If no modifiers are present, the location is interpreted as a    prefix match. This means that the location given will be matched 
>     against the beginning of the request URI to determine a match.
> - =: If an equal sign is used, this block will be considered a match if the request URI exactly matches the location given.
> - ~: If a tilde    modifier is present, this location will be interpreted as a    case-sensitive regular expression match.
> - ~*: If a tilde and asterisk    modifier is used, the location block will be interpreted as a    case-insensitive regular expression match.
> - ^~: If a carat and tilde    modifier is present, and if this block is selected as the best    non-regular expression match, regular
>     expression matching will not    take place.

In short, you're using a prefix match as you have no ~ character. Once you fix that, I don't see any regular expression here. Here's a location with a regex I use for caching images as an example

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico|svg)$ {
  expires 8d;
}
```

You could ask another question if you need help working out the regular expression you need. I don't use them much so it takes me a while to get back up to speed each time I do it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I stated in my question, even a leading tilde (plus space) does not work

Comment: When I put your regex "/profile/491ecdcd4.png$" into https://regex101.com/ it told me it wasn't a valid regex because "An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash". Perhaps you should have a play with regex101.com to make sure your regex is working?

Comment: Yes, because regex101 uses slashes as the delimiters. But even with escaping (is valid in regex101 then) it does not work: `~* \/profile\/`

Comment: Not even `~* profile` works

Comment: You need to edit your question to make it clear what you're trying to achieve. Clearly you want to do something with a regex around the word "profile", but you haven't said what you're trying to achieve.